# how to remove an element from array stored in json object? | angular js | scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have  json object with following structure:

```
$scope.sellAccessories[0]=[
{id: [178], item_name: ["Nescafe","ggfftrww"], quantity: [1], total_price:[300]}
]
```

my problem is that i want to remove some elements from the array before i send the json object to the server side.

i tried to remove the second element in the array `item_name` which is **ggfftrww** using the splice function:

```
var index = $scope.sellAccessories[0].item_name.indexOf($scope.sellAccessories[0].item_name[1]);

if (index > -1) {
   $scope.sellAccessories[0].item_name.splice(index, 1);
}
```

but it didn't work.

thanks in advance this is stopping my work flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to bring out your item_name to a variable, perform the splice and then set the result to the object property as follows;

```
var itemToChange=$scope.sellAccessories[0].item_name;
var index = itemToChange.indexOf(itemToChange[1]);

if (index > -1) {
   itemToChange.splice(index, 1);
   $scope.sellAccessories[0].item_name=itemToChange;
}
```

Comment: this is easy and nice!

Comment: `splice` mutates the original array; the last line there is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a *method of formatting a string*; if what you're dealing with isn't a string, call it an `object` or `array.`

From your question, `sellAccessories` is an *array of arrays* - it's not just a plain array, so you can't just access the `item_name` through `sellAccessories[0].item_name`.

Objects are only *references to memory locations*, so you can simply access the array and remove the appropriate property:

```js
const scope = { sellAccessories: [] };
scope.sellAccessories[0] = [{
  id: [178],
  item_name: ["Nescafe", "ggfftrww"],
  quantity: [1],
  total_price: [300]
}]
const { item_name } = scope.sellAccessories[0][0];
item_name.splice(item_name.indexOf('ggfftrww'));
console.log(item_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing with multiple steps, you could do it with single line as mentioned below.

$scope.sellAccessories[0] = $scope.sellAccessories[0]['item_name'].splice(0,1);